# Adding JObject to JArray

Tags: c#, json

Im trying to add a new class called "Company" to a Json Array called Companies. I'm doing this using C# and Json .net Ive tried many different things. I have them all pares out and in Jobjects ready to be molded together but I can't find a way to do so. Im trying to get it to find "Companies" then insert the new company object in there.

This is what im trying to do.

```
public void CreateNewCompany()
{
    Company company = new Company
    {
        CompanyName = textBox1.Text,
        IPO = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text),
        Category = CategorycomboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(),
        Description = textBox4.Text,
        StartDate = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text)
    };

    AddProductListItemsToFinishedJSON(company);
    AddNewsArticlesListItemsToFinishedJSON(company);

    JObject newCompany = JObject.FromObject(company);

    string existingFileContents = File.ReadAllText(path);
    string newFileContents      = newCompany.ToString();          

    var existingFileContentsToJSON = JObject.Parse(existingFileContents);
    var newFileContentsToJSON      = JObject.Parse(newFileContents);

    Debug.WriteLine(existingFileContents);

    SaveJSONFile(company);
}

public void SaveJSONFile(Company localcompany)
{
    if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(@"D:\", "comp.json")))
    {
        File.Delete(Path.Combine(@"D:\", "comp.json"));
    }       

    string RawJSON       = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(localcompany);
    string FormattedJSON = JToken.Parse(RawJSON).ToString(Formatting.Indented);

    //Console.WriteLine(FormattedJSON);
    File.WriteAllText(@"D:\comp.json", FormattedJSON);
}
```

These are the classes

```
public class Company
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public double IPO { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int    StartDate { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products                        = new List<Product>();
    public List<NewsArticle> CompanySpecificNewsArticles = new List<NewsArticle>();
    public List<string> EavesDropperList = new List<string>();
}

public class Product
{
    [JsonProperty("ProductName")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

public class NewsArticle
{
    [JsonProperty("Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

This is what the Json Looks like and I want to add it to 'Companies'

```
{
   "Companies":[
      {
         "CompanyName":"",
         "IPO":25.0,
         "Category":"Gaming",
         "Description":"A video game company",
         "StartDate":"1-1-2000",
         "Products":[
            {
               "ProductName":""
            },
            {
               "ProductName":""
            }
         ],
         "CompanySpecificNewsArticles":[
            {
               "Type":"Positive",
               "Content":"This company has had a very good year!"
            },
            {
               "Type":"Negative",
               "Content":"This company has had a very bad year!"
            },
            {
               "Type":"Neutral",
               "Content":"This company is doing okay, I guess"
            }
         ],
         "CompanySpecificEavesdropper":[
            {
               "Type":"Positive",
               "Content":"This company has had a very good year!"
            },
            {
               "Type":"Negative",
               "Content":"This company has had a very bad year!"
            },
            {
               "Type":"Neutral",
               "Content":"This company is doing okay, I guess!"
            }
         ]
      }
      //,
      // Other companies omitted
   ]
}
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could create a [mcve] of your code -- i.e. a console app we could compile and run?  Currently your code doesn't compile, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/hrKnlC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JSON file is just a text file, so there's no straightforward way to insert a record into the middle of the file.  Instead, you will need to load the entire file into some in-memory representation, add your `Company` to the `"Companies"` array, then re-serialize the file back to disk.

To accomplish this, first create the following extension methods:

```
public class JsonExtensions
{
    public static T LoadFromFileOrCreateDefault<T>(string path, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null) where T : new()
    {
        var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);

        try
        {
            using (var file = File.OpenText(path))
            {
                return (T)JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings).Deserialize(file, typeof(T));
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            return new T();
        }
    }

    public static void SaveToFile<T>(T root, string path, Formatting formatting = Formatting.None, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        using (var file = File.CreateText(path))
        using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(file) { Formatting = formatting })
        {
            JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings).Serialize(writer, root);
        }           
    }
}
```

Now you can add your `Company` to the array in `CreateNewCompany()` as follows:

```
var root = JsonExtensions.LoadFromFileOrCreateDefault<JObject>(Path);

var companiesArray = (JArray)root["Companies"] ?? (JArray)(root["Companies"] = new JArray());

companiesArray.Add(JObject.FromObject(company));

JsonExtensions.SaveToFile(root, Path, Formatting.Indented);
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eHOtMu).

Incidentally, since your entire file seems to have a fixed schema, you could simplify your code and get slightly better performance by deserializing directly to some root data model, omitting the `JObject` representation entirely.

First, create the following root data model:

```
public class CompanyList
{
    public List<Company> Companies { get; } = new List<Company>();
}
```

Then modify `CreateNewCompany()` as follows:

```
var root = JsonExtensions.LoadFromFileOrCreateDefault<CompanyList>(Path);

root.Companies.Add(company);

JsonExtensions.SaveToFile(root, Path, Formatting.Indented);
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kR5xt7).

Notes:

- By using generics in `JsonExtensions` we can use the same code to load from, and save to, a file, for both `JObject` and `CompanyList`.
- Serializing directly from and to your file without loading to an intermediate `string` should improve performance as explained in *[Performance Tips: Optimize Memory Usage](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#MemoryUsage)*.
- `Company.StartDate` is declared to be an `int`, however in your JSON it appears as a non-numeric `string`:

  ```
  "StartDate": "1-1-2000"
  ```

  You will need to adjust your data model to account for this.
- There is no need to manually delete the old file as [`File.CreateText(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.createtext?view=netframework-4.8) *creates or opens a file for writing UTF-8 encoded text. If the file already exists, its contents are overwritten.*

  Alternatively you might want to write to a temporary file and then overwrite the old file only after serialization finishes successfully.
- It is better to catch the `FileNotFoundException` from `File.OpenText()` rather than checking `File.Exists()` manually in case the file is somehow deleted in between the two calls.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed description. This helped greatly

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea of what you should be doing

```
public void CreateNewCompany()
{
    Company company = new Company
    {
        CompanyName = "New Company",
        IPO = Convert.ToDouble("0.2"),
        Category = "Sample Category",
        Description = "Sample Description",
        StartDate = Convert.ToInt32("2009")
    };

    AddProductListItemsToFinishedJSON(company);
    AddNewsArticlesListItemsToFinishedJSON(company);

    SaveJSONFile(company);

}

public static void SaveJSONFile(Company localcompany)
{
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        JObject arr = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(path)));
        (arr["Companies"] as JArray).Add(JToken.FromObject(localcompany));
        string RawJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arr);
        string FormattedJSON = JToken.Parse(RawJSON).ToString(Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText(path, FormattedJSON);
    }
    else
    {
        JObject arr = new JObject();
        arr.Add("Companies", new JArray());
        (arr["Companies"] as JArray).Add(JToken.FromObject(localcompany));
        string RawJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arr);
        string FormattedJSON = JToken.Parse(RawJSON).ToString(Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText(path, FormattedJSON);
    }
}
```

Delete your existing json file then run this code. The first run creates the file with one object while subsequent runs adds object to it. You can refactor the code.

Json file will have the format below

```
{
  "Companies": [
    {
      "Products": [],
      "CompanySpecificNewsArticles": [],
      "EavesDropperList": [],
      "CompanyName": "New Company",
      "IPO": 0.2,
      "Category": "Sample Category",
      "Description": "Sample Description",
      "StartDate": 2009
    },
    {
      "Products": [],
      "CompanySpecificNewsArticles": [],
      "EavesDropperList": [],
      "CompanyName": "New Company",
      "IPO": 0.2,
      "Category": "Sample Category",
      "Description": "Sample Description",
      "StartDate": 2009
    }
  ]
}
```

as per your comment on the order, you can set order on you class like below

```
public class Company
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = 0)]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
    public double IPO { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 3)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 4)]
    public int StartDate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 5)]

    public List<Product> Products = new List<Product>();
    [JsonProperty(Order = 6)]
    public List<NewsArticle> CompanySpecificNewsArticles = new List<NewsArticle>();
    [JsonProperty(Order = 7)]
    public List<string> EavesDropperList = new List<string>();
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why Products, News, and eavesdropper is on the top when making a new company? Is there any way to make them go to the bottom? Thanks again for the help I appreciate it

Comment: @JackSoder see my edited answer, you can achieve this using an order property